# How to empty the content of a log file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a process which is continuously writing into a log file. I want to empty the contents of the log file without having to restart the process.

I have used various commands:

```
: > log.txt
echo "" > log.txt
truncate -s 0 log.txt
cat /dev/null > log.txt
```

They all truncate/empty the content of the log file but only temporarily. When a few minutes later process updates the content, log file size (and contents) goes back to (and newer content) what it originally was.

what might be going on and how I can permanently empty the log file contents ?

Comment: You could use `>>` to append the newer content to a file.

Comment: log file for the running process cannot be changed.  I want to rotate the logs at mid-night every day without having to restart the process which cant auto-rotate the log files. So previous days log file is are archived and log file is emptied to be filled again until next mid-night.

Answer (score 1):

For me a permanently empty log is done with simply link it to the black hole named: `/dev/null`
So try it (as root) by yourself with: `rm log.txt && ln -sfv /dev/null log.txt`

Thats not only for security reason.
On a Raspberry Pi or embedded devices it makes the Memory Card living much longer.

Unwanted history files i link in this way for security reason...

```
# ls -lah .*history
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug  6  2020 .ash_history -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 12  2020 .bash_history -> /dev/null
```

...so every session starts with an empty one.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want to achieve. I want to rotate the logs at mid-night every day without having to restart the process which cant auto-rotate the log files. So previous days log file is are archived and log file is emptied to be filled again until next mid-night.

Comment: @tanatan You really should look into the `logrotate` command and its man-page https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html

Comment: thanks @LéaGris. Had a quick look but not sure how this will fix the issue I am facing "The commands truncate/empty the content of the log file but only until process adds more logs to the log file. When a few minutes later process updates the log file, log file size goes back to what it originally was.  I am not sure how the old content comes back in the log file when I had just emptied is using one of the command."